# Knockout disable select option caption

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-select

With knockout 2.3.0 the `optionsAfterRender` binding has been introduced so that the options can be changed quite flexibly.

I'd like to disable the options caption. At the moment I'm doing

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsCaption:'please select', optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) { ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {disable: !item}, item); }"></select>
```

which works, but I have to copy and paste the `optionsAfterRender` function everywhere. I've been trying to create a custom bindingHandler to do it in one place, but I'm having difficulty. 
This is my bindingHandler so far:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.disableOptionsCaption = {
    init: function (element) {

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            optionsAfterRender: function (option, item) {

                ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {
                    disable: !item
                }, item);

            }
        });

    }
};
```

[I've also created a fiddle here that shows the working version and non-working.](http://jsfiddle.net/nickkell/tXXzd/1/) Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply all bindings together, not step by step, like this:

Html

```
<select data-bind="disableOptionsCaption:{}"></select>
```

JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.disableOptionsCaption = {
    init: function (element,valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            options: viewModel.items,
            optionsCaption: 'please select',
            optionsAfterRender: function (option, item) {

                ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {
                    disable: !item
                }, item);

            }
        });
    }
};
```